# Scope problems within angular directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm following the lessons on egghead.io (http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication), and I'm having some scope problems. When I mouse over `<superhero flash>flash</superhero>`, I am getting a blank array instead of 'speed'. However, when I add the flash directive to the second superhero directive, it prints it correctly. I am wondering if there are any scope problems I am having?

http://jsfiddle.net/9q6MG/

Console (on mouse over on flash)

```
Expected: 'speed'    
Actual: []
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ewmCT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of the shared scope used by the superhero directive.

The superhero directive uses the parent elements scope as its own scope because you are not using child/isolated scopes for the directive. There for both the superhero elements in your sample shares the same scope.

So first superhero creates a empty array property `abilities` and since it has a `speed` directive adds `speed` to it, then when the second superhero element is compiled and processed it overrides this property again with a empty array because both of them works in the same scope

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('superhero', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.abilities = [];

            this.addStrength = function () {
                console.log('adding strength', $scope.$id);
                $scope.abilities.push('strength');
                console.log($scope.abilities);
            }

            this.addSpeed = function () {
                console.log('adding speed', $scope.$id);
                $scope.abilities.push('speed');
                console.log($scope.abilities);
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            console.log('link', scope.$id, scope.abilities)
            element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
                console.log('me', scope.$id, scope.abilities)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D7AV9/)

Comment: Just to check - does this mean that each directive has an individual scope?

Comment: @DanTang once you have define `scope:true` the element with the directive will have a individual scope